# Problemas con trigger en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert, update, delete

necesito ayuda con este trigger que su objetivo sería guardar una auditoría de los datos de la tabla paises, donde quisiera guardar en el formato NombreColumna:-:Valor::-::NombreColumna:-:Valor, de todas las columnas que su
DATA_TYPE sea ('INT', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR').

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia la agradecería, estoy tratando de hacer el insert primero, la sería para las tres accciones, en el update solo guardaría las columnas que fueron modificadas, no todas.

El mayor problema problema hasta ahora es en la línea EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLTEXT;, no encuentro como ejecutar esa sentencia y que pueda utilizar el valor de las variables declaradas.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises ON dbo.Paises
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @SysUser    varchar(100)
    DECLARE @FullName   varchar(250)
    DECLARE @TableName  varchar(250)
    DECLARE @Action     varchar(50) 
    DECLARE @OldValue   varchar(Max)
    DECLARE @NewValue   varchar(Max)
    DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME AS varchar(100)
    DECLARE @DATA_TYPE AS varchar(100)
    DECLARE @SQLTEXT AS nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @SEPARATOR AS VARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @SEPARATORCOLUMN AS VARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @COLUMN_VALUE AS nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @DATAFULLTEXT AS NVARCHAR(Max) 
    
    SET @TableName = 'Paises';

    DECLARE ColumnInfo CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='paises' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('INT', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR') ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

    SET @SQLTEXT = ''
    SET @SEPARATOR = ':::'
    SET @SEPARATORCOLUMN = '::::'
    SET @DATAFULLTEXT = ''
    
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Inserted )
                BEGIN
                    --UPDATE
                    SET @OldValue = ''
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --DELETE
                    SET @OldValue = ''
                END  
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            --INSERT
            SELECT @SysUser = I.LastUserUpdate FROM Inserted I;
            IF @SysUser <> '' 
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @FullName = FullName FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @SysUser    
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SELECT  @SysUser = login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
                    SET @FullName = 'Admin for console' 
                END

            OPEN ColumnInfo
            FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnInfo INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE
            WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @SQLTEXT = 'DECLARE @SEPARATOR AS VARCHAR(5);';
                SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'DECLARE @SEPARATORCOLUMN AS VARCHAR(5);';
                SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'DECLARE @COLUMN_VALUE AS nvarchar(Max);';
                SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'DECLARE @DATAFULLTEXT AS NVARCHAR(Max);';

                SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'SET @SEPARATOR = '':-:'';';  
                SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'SET @SEPARATORCOLUMN = ''::-::'';';
                
                SET @SQLTEXT = CONCAT(@SQLTEXT, N'SELECT @COLUMN_VALUE = Coalesce(CAST( ', @COLUMN_NAME, ' AS VARCHAR(Max)), '''') FROM Inserted WHERE id = 1 ;');
                SET @SQLTEXT = CONCAT(@SQLTEXT, N' SET @DATAFULLTEXT = @DATAFULLTEXT + @SEPARATORCOLUMN +''', @COLUMN_NAME,''' + @SEPARATOR + @COLUMN_VALUE;');

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLTEXT;
                
                FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnInfo INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE
            END
            CLOSE ColumnInfo
            DEALLOCATE ColumnInfo

            INSERT  INTO dbo.AuditLogs ( SysUser, FullName, TableName, Action, OldValue, NewValue)
                    SELECT  @SysUser, @FullName, @TableName, 'INSERT', '', @DATAFULLTEXT FROM Inserted
        END
GO
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tratas de hacer código dinámico cuando puedes usar código normal? Comparte la estructura de tu tabla y te puedo ayudar a hacer más simple el trigger.

Comment: ¿Qué debería de pasar si se afectan más de una fila a la vez?

Comment: Saludos, Luis aquí te comparto el ejemplo donde ya logré que me funcionara el Insert y Delete, pero el update quiero solo guardar las columnas que se modifican.

Answer (score 0):

Luis aquí te comparto el ejemplo donde ya logré que me funcionara el Insert y Delete, pero el update quiero solo guardar las columnas que se modifican.

```
IF Exists ( SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'Paises' )
  DROP TABLE Paises
GO

CREATE TABLE Paises(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pais] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [abreviatura] [char](10) NULL,
    [LastUserUpdate] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK40] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

IF Exists ( SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'AuditLogs' )
  DROP TABLE AuditLogs
GO

CREATE TABLE AuditLogs(
    id                int             IDENTITY(1,1),
    SysDate           datetime2(7)    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    SysUser           varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    FullName          varchar(250)    NULL,
    TableName         varchar(250)    NULL,
    Action            varchar(250)    NULL,
    OldValue          text            NULL,
    NewValue          text            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_AuditLogs PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id)
)
go

IF Exists ( SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'Users' )
  DROP TABLE Users
GO

CREATE TABLE Users(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_Users] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName, FullName, Password) VALUES ('User1', 'User test 1', '*111*')
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName, FullName, Password) VALUES ('User2', 'User test 2', '*111*')
GO


IF Exists( SELECT A.Name FROM SysObjects A WHERE A.Name = 'TR_Audit_Paises')
    DROP TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises ON dbo.Paises
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @SysUser    varchar(100);
    DECLARE @FullName   varchar(250);
    DECLARE @TableName  varchar(250);
    DECLARE @Action     varchar(50);    
    DECLARE @OldValue   nvarchar(Max);
    DECLARE @NewValue   nvarchar(Max);
    DECLARE @Count      INT;
    
    SET @TableName = 'Paises';
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Inserted )
                BEGIN
                    --UPDATE
                    SET @OldValue = ''
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --DELETE
                    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Deleted;

                    IF ( @Count > 0 )
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @SysUser = LastUserUpdate FROM Deleted;
                        IF @SysUser <> '' 
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @FullName = FullName FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @SysUser    
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT  @SysUser = login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
                                SET @FullName = 'Admin for console' 
                            END

                        SELECT * INTO #_TmpDeleted from Deleted;

                        WHILE (Exists(SELECT * FROM #_TmpDeleted))
                        BEGIN
                            SET @OldValue = REPLACE( (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM #_TmpDeleted FOR XML AUTO), '/>', '' );
                            SET @OldValue = SUBSTRING(@OldValue, CHARINDEX(' ', @OldValue) + 1, LEN(@OldValue));
                            SET @OldValue = REPLACE(@OldValue,'" ' ,'": ' ); 
                            SET @OldValue = SUBSTRING(@OldValue, 0, CHARINDEX('": LastUserUpdate="', @OldValue) + 1 );
            
                            INSERT  INTO dbo.AuditLogs ( SysUser, FullName, TableName, Action, OldValue, NewValue)
                                    VALUES ( @SysUser, @FullName, @TableName, 'DELETE', @OldValue, '' );

                            DELETE TOP(1) FROM #_TmpDeleted;
                        END
                    END

                END  
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            --INSERT
            SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Inserted;

            IF ( @Count > 0 )
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SysUser = LastUserUpdate FROM Inserted;
                IF @SysUser <> '' 
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @FullName = FullName FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @SysUser    
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT  @SysUser = login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
                        SET @FullName = 'Admin for console' 
                    END

                SELECT * INTO #_TmpInserted from Inserted;

                WHILE (Exists(SELECT * FROM #_TmpInserted))
                BEGIN
                    SET @NewValue = REPLACE( (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM #_TmpInserted FOR XML AUTO), '/>', '' );
                    SET @NewValue = SUBSTRING(@NewValue, CHARINDEX(' ', @NewValue) + 1, LEN(@NewValue));
                    SET @NewValue = REPLACE(@NewValue,'" ' ,'": ' ); 
                    SET @NewValue = SUBSTRING(@NewValue, 0, CHARINDEX('": LastUserUpdate="', @NewValue) + 1 );
            
                    INSERT  INTO dbo.AuditLogs ( SysUser, FullName, TableName, Action, OldValue, NewValue)
                            VALUES ( @SysUser, @FullName, @TableName, 'INSERT', '', @NewValue );

                    DELETE TOP(1) FROM #_TmpInserted;
                END

            END
        END
GO


select * from paises
delete from paises
select * from AuditLogs
delete from AuditLogs

insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('Mexico', 'Mex', 'Laysi');
insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('China', 'Chi', 'Juan');
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('Ecuador', 'ECU', 'Jc');
insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('Brasil', 'BRA', 'Badillo');
insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('España', 'ESP', 'Badillo');
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

delete from paises where id = 100;
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

delete from paises where abreviatura IN ('ECU', 'BRA');
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

delete from paises where abreviatura = 'CHI';
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

Select * into #_paises from paises;
select * from #_paises

Insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) 
    select pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate from #_paises;

DROP TABLE #_paises
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs
```

Comment: Ten presente que a los usuarios no les llega una notificación cuando respondes a tu pregunta. Si quieres notificar algo a un usuario en particular, déjale un comentario en su respuesta, o menciónalo (con @) en los comentarios de tu pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, no es necesaria más de una respuesta (parece ser que duplicaste el contenido de tu respuesta). Elimina la que no corresponda.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como haría el trigger. Es un código que llega a ser más sencillo porque no hay que definir toda la lógica, sino que todo se encuentra en un solo SELECT. Esto ayuda a insertar varias filas a la vez y mejorar el rendimiento.

Es algo tan genérico y estructurado que los cambios para adaptarlo a otras tablas es solo modificar el nombre de la tabla y dos filas por cada columna que tengas en la tabla.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises ON dbo.Paises
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SysUser    varchar(100);

SELECT  @SysUser = login_name 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
WHERE session_id = @@SPID;

INSERT INTO dbo.AuditLogs( 
    SysUser, 
    FullName, 
    TableName, 
    Action, 
    OldValue, 
    NewValue
)
SELECT ISNULL( i.LastUserUpdate, @SysUser), 
        ISNULL( u.FullName,  'Admin for console' ),
        'Paises',
        CASE WHEN d.id IS NULL THEN 'INSERT'
            WHEN i.id IS NULL THEN 'DELETE'
            ELSE 'UPDATE' END,
        CASE WHEN d.id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT( 'id="', d.id, --El ID siempre tiene que ir
                                                    IIF( d.pais <> i.pais COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '":pais=",' + d.pais, ''), --Validamos si cambió el pais. Utilizamos una intercalación binaria para identificar cualquier cambio
                                                    IIF( d.abreviatura <> i.abreviatura COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '":abreviatura:"' + d.abreviatura, ''), --Validamos si cambió la abreviatura
                                                    '"') END, --Cerramos la cadena
        CASE WHEN i.id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT( 'id="', i.id, --El ID siempre tiene que ir
                                                    IIF( d.pais <> i.pais COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '":pais=",' + i.pais, ''), --Validamos si cambió el pais. Utilizamos una intercalación binaria para identificar cualquier cambio
                                                    IIF( d.abreviatura <> i.abreviatura COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, '":abreviatura:"' + i.abreviatura, ''), --Validamos si cambió la abreviatura
                                                    '"') END --Cerramos la cadena
FROM inserted       AS i
FULL JOIN deleted   AS d ON i.id = d.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Users AS u ON i.LastUserUpdate = u.UserName 
                         OR (u.UserName = @SysUser AND i.LastUserUpdate IS NULL);
GO
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Luis verdaderamente está muy buena la idea y muy simplificada.

Answer (score 0):

he logrado realizar el trigger para los eventos Insert y Delete, pero aún no para el Update, pues solo necesito guardar las columnas que se han modificado realmente, no a todas.

Les dejo los cambios para cualquier aporte.

```
IF Exists ( SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'Paises' )
  DROP TABLE Paises
GO

CREATE TABLE Paises(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pais] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [abreviatura] [char](10) NULL,
    [LastUserUpdate] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK40] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

IF Exists ( SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'AuditLogs' )
  DROP TABLE AuditLogs
GO

CREATE TABLE AuditLogs(
    id                int             IDENTITY(1,1),
    SysDate           datetime2(7)    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    SysUser           varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    FullName          varchar(250)    NULL,
    TableName         varchar(250)    NULL,
    Action            varchar(250)    NULL,
    OldValue          text            NULL,
    NewValue          text            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_AuditLogs PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id)
)
go

IF Exists ( SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'Users' )
  DROP TABLE Users
GO

CREATE TABLE Users(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_Users] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

IF Exists( SELECT A.Name FROM SysObjects A WHERE A.Name = 'TR_Audit_Paises')
    DROP TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises ON dbo.Paises
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SysUser    varchar(100);
    DECLARE @FullName   varchar(250);
    DECLARE @TableName  varchar(250);
    DECLARE @Action     varchar(50);    
    DECLARE @OldValue   nvarchar(Max);
    DECLARE @NewValue   nvarchar(Max);
    DECLARE @Count      INT;
    
    SET @TableName = 'Paises';
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN  
            IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )
                BEGIN
                    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Inserted )
                        BEGIN
                            --UPDATE
                            SET @OldValue = ''
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            --DELETE
                            SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Deleted;

                            IF ( @Count > 0 )
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @SysUser = LastUserUpdate FROM Deleted;
                                IF @SysUser <> '' 
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT @FullName = FullName FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @SysUser    
                                    END
                                ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT  @SysUser = login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
                                        SET @FullName = 'Admin for console' 
                                    END

                                SELECT * INTO #_TmpDeleted from Deleted;

                                WHILE (Exists(SELECT * FROM #_TmpDeleted))
                                BEGIN
                                    SET @OldValue = REPLACE( (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM #_TmpDeleted FOR XML AUTO), '/>', '' );
                                    SET @OldValue = SUBSTRING(@OldValue, CHARINDEX(' ', @OldValue) + 1, LEN(@OldValue));
                                    SET @OldValue = REPLACE(@OldValue,'" ' ,'": ' ); 
                                    SET @OldValue = SUBSTRING(@OldValue, 0, CHARINDEX('": LastUserUpdate="', @OldValue) + 1 );
                    
                                    INSERT  INTO dbo.AuditLogs ( SysUser, FullName, TableName, Action, OldValue, NewValue)
                                            VALUES ( @SysUser, @FullName, @TableName, 'DELETE', @OldValue, '' );

                                    DELETE TOP(1) FROM #_TmpDeleted;
                                END
                            END

                        END  
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --INSERT
                    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Inserted;

                    IF ( @Count > 0 )
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @SysUser = LastUserUpdate FROM Inserted;
                        IF @SysUser <> '' 
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @FullName = FullName FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @SysUser    
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT  @SysUser = login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
                                SET @FullName = 'Admin for console' 
                            END

                        SELECT * INTO #_TmpInserted from Inserted;

                        WHILE (Exists(SELECT * FROM #_TmpInserted))
                        BEGIN
                            SET @NewValue = REPLACE( (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM #_TmpInserted FOR XML AUTO), '/>', '' );
                            SET @NewValue = SUBSTRING(@NewValue, CHARINDEX(' ', @NewValue) + 1, LEN(@NewValue));
                            SET @NewValue = REPLACE(@NewValue,'" ' ,'": ' ); 
                            SET @NewValue = SUBSTRING(@NewValue, 0, CHARINDEX('": LastUserUpdate="', @NewValue) + 1 );
                    
                            INSERT  INTO dbo.AuditLogs ( SysUser, FullName, TableName, Action, OldValue, NewValue)
                                    VALUES ( @SysUser, @FullName, @TableName, 'INSERT', '', @NewValue );

                            DELETE TOP(1) FROM #_TmpInserted;
                        END

                    END
                END
        COMMIT TRAN;
 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN; 
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  
   
        SELECT  
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  
   
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
                   @ErrorSeverity,
                   @ErrorState 
                   );    
    END CATCH
END 
GO



INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName, FullName, Password) VALUES ('User1', 'User test 1', '*111*')
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserName, FullName, Password) VALUES ('User2', 'User test 2', '*111*')
GO

select * from paises
delete from paises
select * from AuditLogs
delete from AuditLogs

insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('Mexico', 'Mex', 'User1');
insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('China', 'Chi', 'User3');
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('Ecuador', 'ECU', 'User4');
insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('Brasil', 'BRA', 'User2');
insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) values ('España', 'ESP', 'User2');
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

delete from paises where id = 100;
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

delete from paises where abreviatura IN ('ECU', 'BRA');
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

delete from paises where abreviatura = 'CHI';
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs

Select * into #_paises from paises;
select * from #_paises

Insert into paises (pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate) 
    select pais, abreviatura, LastUserUpdate from #_paises;

DROP TABLE #_paises
select * from paises
select * from AuditLogs
```

Gracias

Comment: Por cierto, no es necesaria más de una respuesta (parece ser que duplicaste el contenido de [esta otra](/a/612567)). Elimina la que no corresponda.